# Query en Mysql para obtener registros que tengan los mismos registros en otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tres tablas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con la siguiente información:
Receta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ingrediente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

RECETA_INGREDIENTE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora por ejemplo quiero traer las recetas que tengan los ingredientes `leche(6) y Azúcar(7)`
El resultado que espero es:

```
Pay de limón
Chocolate
```

Intente lo siguiente sin éxito:

```
select * from RECETA_INGREDIENTE RI
INNER JOIN RECETA R 
ON R.ID_RECETA = RI.ID_RECETA
INNER JOIN INGREDIENTE I 
ON I.ID_INGREDIENTE = RI.ID_INGREDIENTE 
where RI.ID_INGREDIENTE = 6 AND RI.ID_INGREDIENTE = 7;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta query basicamente selecciona todos los ingredientes que necesitas en el WHERE y el COUNT DISTINCT se asegura que esten los 2 diferentes,  y se agrupa por receta.

```
SELECT r.NOMBRE, i.NOMBRE FROM
RECETA r
JOIN RECETA_INGREDIENTE ri ON ri.ID_RECETA = r.ID_RECETA
JOIN INGREDIENTE i ON i.ID_INGREDIENTE = ri.ID_INGREDIENTE
WHERE i.ID_INGREDIENTE IN(6,7)
GROUP BY r.ID_RECETA
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.ID_INGREDIENTE ) = 2
```

[Prueba en sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db386/6/0)

Answer (score 0):

Este el único modo en que se me ocurre aunque un poco forzado:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(receta.nombre)
from receta
join receta_ingrediente
on receta.id_receta = receta_ingrediente.id_receta
WHERE 
(receta_ingrediente.id_ingrediente IN (6,7))
AND receta.nombre <> "sopa";
```

Hago uso de distinct por que mas de una receta usa alguno de los ingredientes listados, entonce evitamos que nos muestre repetidos

hago uso del operador IN para indicarle que busque las coincidencias entre esos dos parametros

al final le indico que de la tabla receta y de la columna nombre descarte con `<>` el nombre de sopa que finalmente en el resultado final resulta ser el id 5 el cual necesitamos quitar del resultado final

Aqui el fiddle donde desarrollé el ejercicio https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=8143474771046319655831b2d3099629